# Flutter/Firebase-How to perform delete document functionality when document ID is not known?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and developing an application in which I am displaying data in the from of ListView. There is a delete IconButton in it. I want that the selected ListTile data should be deleted. It is displaying data in the form of List but not deleting.
After I have added the deleteData() method. It is showing the following error:

> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/silver_multi_box_adaptor.dart':Failed
>   assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index'
>   : is not true.

Any help is highly appreciated. Here is what I have done so far:

```
class OrderRequestModel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: UserOrderRequestModel(),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserOrderRequestModel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserOrderRequestModelState createState() {
    return _UserOrderRequestModelState();
  }
}

class _UserOrderRequestModelState extends State<UserOrderRequestModel> {
  deleteData(docId) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('order_tbl')
        .document(docId)
        .delete()
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData() async*{
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance.collection('order_tbl').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots();
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
    String _string =getTimeDifferenceFromNow(record.timestamp.toDate());
    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.animal),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: new ListTile(
            title: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  "${record.quantity} kg ${record.animal} - ${record.mobile}",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                new Text(
                  _string,
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
              onPressed: () => deleteData(data.documentID),
            ),

            subtitle: new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: new Text(
                record.address,
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12.0,),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your data is updated but the state remains the same. just add: setState(() {}); in deleteData method after deleting data from firestore.

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/material/material.dart': Failed assertion: line 608 pos 12: 'referenceBox.attached': is not true.@SanketVekariya

Comment: 'child==null || indexOf(child)>index' is not true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this should work, I have changed your code to one of mine which is quite working.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDeletingApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google SignIn',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: DeleteDataFromFireStore(),
    );
  }
}
class DeleteDataFromFireStore extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Delete Data from Firestore")),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: db.collection('order_tbl').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap:() async { await db.collection('order_tbl').document(doc.documentID).delete();},
                            onLongPress:() async { await db.collection('order_tbl').document(doc.documentID).delete();},
                            title: new Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  "${doc.data['quantity']} kg ${doc.data['animal']} - ${doc.data['mobile']}",
                                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                                ),
//                                Text(
//                                  "${doc.data['quantity']}",
//                                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
//                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            subtitle: new Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                              child: new Text("${doc.data['user']} - ${doc.data['address']} ",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12.0,),
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await db.collection('order_tbl').document(doc.documentID).delete();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return SizedBox();
                }
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh its working, I just changed the methods name. Thank you! Got the solution.

Answer (score 10):

- **Delete a single document:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  await collection.doc('document_id').delete();
  ```
- **Deleting some of the documents:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  var snapshot = await collection.where('age', isGreaterThan: 20).get();
  for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
   await doc.reference.delete();
  }
  ```
- **Deleting all the documents:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  var snapshot = await collection.get();
  for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
    await doc.reference.delete();
  }
  ```